# Can you use sed to delete lines based on multiple conditions?

Tags: json, bash, shell, sed

So I have a JSON file that contains lines that I don't want.

I would like to delete all lines that has

```
"Voice": "No"
```

But there are two conditions. For example, given below file

```
{
            "start": 0.0,
            "end": 3.33,
            "segmentId": "00001",
            "primaryType": "Noise",
            "loudnessLevel": "Normal",
            "Voice": "No"
         },
```

I want it to be

```
{
            "start": 0.0,
            "end": 3.33,
            "segmentId": "00001",
            "primaryType": "Noise",
            "loudnessLevel": "Normal"
         },
```

Where the `,` after `Normal` is deleted so that the JSON file structure stays the same.

However, on the other hand,

```
{
            "start": 4.01,
            "end": 13.52,
            "language": "ja",
            "speakerId": "sss",
            "transcriptionData": {
               "content": "content"
            },
            "Voice": "No",
            "segmentLanguages": [
               "j"
            ]
         },
```

would turn into

```
{
            "start": 4.01,
            "end": 13.52,
            "language": "ja",
            "speakerId": "sss",
            "transcriptionData": {
               "content": "content"
            },
            "segmentLanguages": [
               "j"
            ]
         },
```

where `,` above is stays the same to keep the JSON format.

I've tried `sed -i 's/"Voice": "No"/d` but, due to lack of experience, this backfired. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why sed and not jq? Sed doesn't understand JSON format.

Comment: Do you have `jq` or can install it?

Answer (score 4):

You would not use sed for the job but jq:

```
$ jq 'del(.Voice)' sample1
```

Exact output on your data:

```
{
  "start": 0,
  "end": 3.33,
  "segmentId": "00001",
  "primaryType": "Noise",
  "loudnessLevel": "Normal"
}
parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 8, column 11
```

But if you insist on using sed, something like this should do it:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n *"Voice": "No"//g' sample2
```

Output:

```
{
            "start": 4.01,
            "end": 13.52,
            "language": "ja",
            "speakerId": "sss",
            "transcriptionData": {
               "content": "content"
            },
            "segmentLanguages": [
               "j"
            ]
         },
```

I'd use jq.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to use `jq`(made for json), you can use

```
sed -zr 's/,\s+"Voice": "No"//' inputfile
```

This only works when you are sure that you have a line with a `,` before the `Voice` line.